# Resubmission of app in App Store does not show "ready to submit"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

My first app got rejected in App Store due to metadata failure. I deleted the page they were pointing at and I want to resubmit the app to store however the "ready to submit" button is not getting appeared on the page. They are asking me an explanation for the registration page on which I wanted some user information. How would I resubmit it?

P.S:- if I will delete the application. I won't be able to use the same name for app for second time and I don't want that.

Comment: check in bottom of your app

Answer (score 1):

after login, click at your app, on the right side, you have 3 to 4 options as version summary, binary details, status history. Go to binary details and then click at reject this binary if you have an option, then re submit with uploading new binary.

Comment: @Mahesh...You can reject the binary you have submitted if its status is any of the following: Missing Screenshot (iOS only), Waiting for Export Compliance, Waiting For Review, In Review, Pending Developer Release, or Pending Apple Release. 
Mine is in state of "METADATA REJECTED"
Link:-http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html

Comment: Clicking the Reject Binary button on the Binary Details page. This action removes your binary from the review queue. You can then submit another update through Application Loader after you move your app back to the Waiting For Upload state in iTunes Connect. If you reject your binary, your app’s status changes to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your binary, the review process starts over from the beginning.

Comment: @Rajneesh071....There is no "Ready to submit the Binary". It only says   Metadata Rejected......